# How to set up a Virtual box virtual machine for the bamboo-mri-1.9.2 stack on heroku.com

Tags: heroku, ruby-1.9, ruby-on-rails-3, bamboo

I would like to set up a Ruby/Rails development environment that mirrors what I would get on heroku.com for the bamboo-mri-1.9.2 stack. I need this so that I can follow along with Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). So I think that I need:

- Debian Lenny 5.0
- git
- curl
- rvm
- Ruby MRI 1.9.2
- Rails 3.0.3
- PostgreSQL - but I'm not sure which version
- Ruby/PostgreSQL drivers
- zlib
- readline
- openssl
- rubygems
- autotest
- drb
- spork

Every time I try a new step in the tutorial I run into problems saying that I am missing a library or a gem, or that a gem didn't load, or whatever. (My computer is Ubuntu 10.4, and was set up nicely to run Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.x).

I did some digging and I eventually figured out how to get openssl and readline working for my system. However, I would like to know if anybody has a repeatable instruction set that will tell me what I need to install to get this development stack on my computer, preferably in a VirtualBox or VMWare VM.

I appreciate any help that  you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't promise this will be *exactly* the same as heroku, the following should be sufficiently similar and a good platform for rails development.

1. Debain Lenny 5.0 (this has very little effect, but we can be sure this matches Heroku)
2. Install RVM, a program to make installing ruby easy. http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/
3. Read the 'rvm notes' and make sure you're ready to start using RVM
4. If required, use RVM to install openssl and/or readline
5. Install Ruby 1.9.2 with the command 'rvm install 1.9.2'
6. Install the gems 'bundler' and 'rails'
7. Install PostrgeSQL from the Debain repositories with the command 'apt-get install postgresql'. Again a small version difference won't make a significant difference, and the Debain repos should have stable version.
8. Create your first app 'rails new -d postgresql'
9. Enjoy your new environment!